# Error-query completed with errors while executing procedure

Tags: sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test(@cid int)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @local int;
SET @local=@cid;
SELECT * FROM DBO.customerDetails WHERE CID=@local;
END
EXECUTE Test 1
```

My procedure takes lot of time to execute...

Comment: What error message are you getting, any specific error code?

Comment: how many records in your db ? most properly the customerDetails table is locked by other process, sp_who2 to see

Comment: if you can accept dirty result, try this, SELECT * FROM DBO.customerDetails(nolock) WHERE CID=@local;

Answer (score 0):

I suspect indexes: either none or bad ones

- Do you have any indexes on `DBO.customerDetails`?
- Is CID the primary key? And is it clustered?
- Should the query return one row?
- Is `CID` the same datatype as the parameter?

Basically, with no or bad indexes you have a table scan. That is, to find the row(s) you want requires all rows to be examined.

An index on CID may not be enough if not clustered because of the key lookup needed to get all other columns.

More explanations requires more information...